# how to build an accumulator array in matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I'm very new to matlab so sorry if this is a dumb question.  I have to following matrices:

```
im = imread('image.jpg');  %<370x366 double>
[y,x] = find(im); %x & y both <1280x1 double>
theta;  %<370x366 double> computed from gradient of image
```

I can currently plot points one at a time like this:

```
plot(x(502) + 120*cos(theta(y(502),x(502))),y(502) + 120*sin(theta(y(502),x(502))));
```

But what I want to do is some how increment an accumulator array, I want to increment the location of acc by 1 for every time value for that location is found.

So if x(502) + 120*cos(theta(y(502),x(502))),y(502) + 120*sin(theta(y(502),x(502)) = (10,10) then acc(10,10) should be incremented by 1.  I'm working with a very large data set so I want to avoid for-loops and use something like this:

```
acc = zeros(size(im));
%increment value when point lands in that location
acc(y,x) = acc(x + 120*cos(theta(y,x)),y + 120*sin(theta(y,x)),'*b')) + 1;
```

It would be nice if the 120 could actually be another matrix containing different radius values as well.

Comment: It is not clear what your desired result is.

Comment: @EitanT updated question for clarity.

Comment: i think you want to implement hough transform?!.

Comment: @HeshamAbouelsoaod yes I am implementing a circular HT, I know there is built in tools but I'm doing it from scratch for a school project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
i = find(im);
```

instead of

```
[y,x] = find(im)
```

wthis will give you linear indice of non zero values

Also, create a meshgrid

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:366,1:370)
```

Now you can index both coordinated and values linearly, for example

`x(520)` is 520-th point x coordinate

`im(520)` is 520-th point gray value

`theta(520)` is 520-th gradient value

So, now you can just plot it:

```
plot(x(i) + 120*cos(theta(i)),y(i) + 120*sin(theta(i)),'b*');
```

`x(i)` means a column of i-th values

`x(i) + 120*cos(theta(i))` means a column of results

**ACCUMULATING**

I think in this case it is ok to loop for accumulating:

```
acc=zeros(size(im));
for ii=1:length(i)
    xx=round(x(ii) + 120*cos(theta(ii)));
    yy=round(y(ii) + 120*sin(theta(ii)));
    acc(xx,yy)=acc(xx,yy)+1;
end;
```

Comment: This is working great! And fast!  Except it was [x,y] = meshgrid(1:366,1:370);  Any idea how to take the extra step and keep track of the values rather than just plot them?  something like acc(i) = x(i) + ... ?

Comment: I think for this you should loop. You need to round values before use them as indices, so it is ok to loop.

Comment: its not quite clear what you mean here, the loop you show increments every pixel, it should only be incremented in the case that the plot equation lands on that pixel.

Comment: Also the problem with bulk operations here is that coordinates may repeat and it is unclear how they will behave. With loop we have only as much cycles as required.

Comment: Thought I would note, I had to add an extra line iii = i(ii); and index by iii not ii for the other matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The `factor` (120 in the example) can be matrix of size of `im` or scalar. The `.*` will do it.

```
im = imread('image.jpg');
[y, x] = meshgrid(1 : size(im, 1), 1 : size(im, 2));
factor = 120 * ones(size(im)); 
theta = gradient(double(image)); % just for example

acc = zeros(size(im));

increment = ((x + factor .* cos(theta)) == 10) &  ((y + factor .* sin(theta)) == 10);
acc = acc + increment;
```

But the comparison to `10` will rarely be true, so you need to allow some range. For example `(9,11)`.

```
e = 1;
increment = abs((x + factor .* cos(theta)) - 10) < e &  abs((y + factor .* sin(theta)) - 10) < e;
```